# How to locate the element as shown in the image

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

The drop down is already selected by value 1 and its not locating through the id or name. How to find the xpath to locate as for the image?

HTML:

```
<select name="ctl05$ddlSelectBox" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl05$ddlSelectBox\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="ctl05_ddlSelectBox" style="height:21px;width:180px;">
    <option selected="selected" value="-1">--Select Box--</option>
    <option value="2742">Box_H026_01</option>
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: Even with the title improved (according to harish R's intentions, hopefully), I don't quite understand `drop down is […] not locating through the id or name` or `the XPath to locate as for the image`

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled `<select>` node. So locate the element  you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("select[name$='ddlSelectBox'][onchange*='ddlSelectBox']")));
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//select[contains(@name, 'ddlSelectBox') and contains(@onchange, 'ddlSelectBox')]")));
  ```